# How to combine two similar methods into one?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-groovy

I have two similar methods that differs in their check conditions. Give two similar methods, how can i combine these two into one? Is this possible with closures?

```
def someCondition = false

def method1() {
    while(!someCondition) {
        def connectionStatus = getConnectionStatus() // return 200, 404, etc.
        if (connectionStatus == 200) {
            someCondition = true
        } else {
            println "repeat until connection is 200"
            sleep 15
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
def someCondition = false

def method2(){
    while(!someCondition) {
        def result = getResult() // A, B, C, etc. 
        if (result in ["A", "B", "C"]) {
            someCondition = true
        } else {
            println "waiting until result is either A, B, or C"
            sleep 15
            result = getResult() // call again to check if result changed
        }
    }
}
```

I could try making it into one method and have different cases where it waits on different if condition depending on the case, but that is no different than just using two different methods. Is there any elegant way to solve this problem in Groovy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a method like this, which takes a Closure that returns `true` if successful:

```
def waitUntil(int sleep = 1, int maxRetries = 10, Closure<Boolean> test) {
    int retries = 0
    while (retries++ < maxRetries && !test()) {
        println "Failed at attempt $retries/$maxRetries, sleeping for $sleep ms before retrying"
        Thread.sleep(sleep)
    }
}
```

Then, you could call it like so:

```
waitUntil {
    getResult() in ["A", "B", "C"]
}
```

Or make it sleep longer with:

```
waitUntil(100) {
    getResult() in ["A", "B", "C"]
}
```

Or make it sleep longer between retries, and only retry 5 times:

```
waitUntil(100, 5) {
    getResult() in ["A", "B", "C"]
}
```

Is that what you meant?

#### Edit

As pointed out, this creates a list each time the closure is called, so for long-running fast looping tasks this could (maybe) create a lot of dead objects for the Garbage Collector to pick up.

A way to fix this, is to pass the expected values in to the main method, and pass this as an argument to the closure.

We then only get one list created:

```
def waitUntil(expectedResult, int sleep = 1, int maxRetries = 10, Closure<Boolean> test) {
    int retries = 0
    while (retries++ < maxRetries && !test(expectedResult)) {
        println "Failed at attempt $retries/$maxRetries, sleeping for $sleep ms before retrying"
        Thread.sleep(sleep)
    }
}

waitUntil(["A", "B", "C"]) {
    getResult() in it
}
```

Comment: Is having the `["A", "B", "C"]` inside the closure going to cause a new instance to be created and populated with each iteration, or is Groovy able to optimize that?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown Interesting...  Despite my initial thoughts, yes I believe it will create a new list each iteration.  You _can_ get around this by making `waitUntil` take a `Closure<Closure<Boolean>>`, and define the list inside the first closure, but outside of the inner closure 

Comment: yes this is what i was looking for! @tim_yates if i were to apply that suggestion how would the application of this approach change?

Comment: @ChrisRagner added an edit to the answer.